# Sublime Text 3 plugin development: access own files

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

The [porting guide](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/porting_guide.html) states that:

> Packages in Sublime Text 3 are able to be run from .sublime-package
>   (i.e., renamed .zip files) files directly, in contrast to Sublime Text 2, which
>   unzipped them prior to running.
>
> While in most changes this should lead to no differences, it is
>   important to keep this in mind if you are accessing files in your
>   package.

So how do I access files in my own package?  My plugin comes with some static files that it must use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sublime.load_resource(name)` where `name` is (from the API docs)

`Loads the given resource. The name should be in the format Packages/Default/Main.sublime-menu.`